# How to use `tracing-subscriber` Rust crate to build a mult-writer, global filter subscriber

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

I'm trying to build a logging setup using the `tracing` and `tracing-subscriber`. However I'm finding the `tracing` ecosystem incredibly abstract and hard to work with.

I'm trying to create Subscriber that has -

- A top level filter based on the target. For e.g. a filter that logs error level for module_a and info level for module_b.[^1](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/filter/struct.EnvFilter.html)
- Two writers[^2](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing/issues/971) each with their own layer level filter.

But I'm unable to create the final subscriber with the existing implementations `Registry` and `FmtSubscriber`.

The problem is that `Registry` does not allow adding an `env_filter` or a top level filter. While the `FmtSubscriber` does not allow adding the writer layers. And it's not clear to me why either of this is not possible when both of them implement the `Subscriber` trait.

```rust
use tracing::{instrument::WithSubscriber, metadata::LevelFilter, subscriber, Level, Subscriber};
use tracing_appender::{
    non_blocking::WorkerGuard,
    rolling::{RollingFileAppender, Rotation},
};
use tracing_subscriber::{
    filter::filter_fn, fmt, layer::Filter, prelude::*, registry::LookupSpan, Registry,
};

fn main() {
    // layer 1 is the file writer
    let rolling_log = RollingFileAppender::new(Rotation::NEVER, "hey", "cool.og");
    let (non_blocking, _) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(rolling_log);
    let layer1 = fmt::Layer::default()
        .with_writer(non_blocking)
        .with_filter(LevelFilter::from(Level::INFO));

    // layer 2 is the stdout writer
    let (non_blocking, _) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(std::io::stdout());
    let layer2 = fmt::Layer::default()
        .with_writer(non_blocking)
        .with_filter(LevelFilter::from(Level::ERROR));

    let top_level_filter: String = "module_a=info,module_b=error".to_string();
    // can't add env_filter/top level filter
    Registry::default().with(layer1).with(layer2).init();
    // can't add multiple writer layers
    fmt().with_env_filter(top_level_filter).init();
}
```

Overall I've found it hard to understand how the the various components in tracing fit together. Any blogs or tutorials explaining how it works will also help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered by [gusrut](https://www.reddit.com/user/gusrust/) in this [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/15isgm7/comment/juy1ono/).

[EnvFilter](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/filter/struct.EnvFilter.html) implements various levels of filtering and can be added to the subscriber using `Subscriber::with` to act as a global filter.

```
use tracing_subscriber::filter::EnvFilter;

let layer1 = ...;
let layer2 = ...;

let global_filter: EnvFilter = "module_a=info,module_b=error".parse()?;
Registry::default().with(layer1).with(layer2).with(global_filter).init();
```